# Obtaining a bound on $\left| \int_0^x t^k \sin{t}dt\right|$

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, upper-lower-bounds

I would like to prove some bound of the form

$$\left|I_k(x)\right| := \left|\int_0^x t^k \sin{t}dt\right| \leqslant Cx^k$$

for a constant $C$ independent of $k$ and $x$. I think $C=1$ should be true whenever $k > 2$ however I am unable to prove it.

It might be useful to remark that following recurrence relation holds

$$I_{k+2} (x) = -x^{k+2} \cos x + (k+2)x^{k+1}\sin x - (k+1)(k+2) I_k(x)$$

and we have the special values

$$I_0(x) = 1-\cos x$$

$$I_1(x) = \sin x - x \cos x$$

Many thanks

Comment: I got that $I_0(x) = \int_0^x \sin(t) dt = 1-\cos(x)$.

Comment: @VVejalla You're absolutely right, thanks. Post edited.

Comment: $C = 2$ works for every $k \geqslant 0$, by the [second mean value theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mean_value_theorem#Second_mean_value_theorem_for_definite_integrals).

Comment: @DanielFischer That's fantastic, thank you very much